# Assign multiple private IPs to a VM in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have 2 Virtual Networks and each of them has a subnet. I want to assign 2 private IP's to a virtual machine. One private IP resides in 1st Virtual Network while second private IP is in 2nd Virtual Network.

I have tried attaching 2 NIC's to the VM, and attached the first private IP to first NIC and second private IP to second NIC.

When I deploy the ARM template it says that second NIC is referring to a subnet which is not in same Virtual Network?

How can I achieve this in Azure?

Comment: somehow i was reading this a public ip's

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve this in Azure ?

As far as I know, Azure does not support this.
For now, Azure just support multiple NICs on the same virtual network.

> Q:Are there any limitations to this feature that customers must be aware
>   of?
>   A:Multiple NIC is supported on Azure VMs (IaaS, Standard SKUs) only;
>   and VMs must be in an Azure Virtual Network.

More information about multiple NICs, please refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/multiple-vm-nics-and-network-virtual-appliances-in-azure/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the existing NIC for the box you are trying to assign the second Private IP,
2. Select IP configuration on the right tab bar,
3. Click on +Add, write a name for your new IP address,
4. Select static Private IP address (it could stay as dynamic as well)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be Azure VNET Peering, which can loosely be thought of as a VPN between the two VNETs via the Azure backbone. This way, all machines in one VNET can talk directly to all those in the second VNET. It assumes that there's no Address Space crossover between the to VNETs, but if that's the case you may always have struggled.
There's a good [article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview) which explains it in more detail.

Answer (score -1):

The best scenario to implement this through below steps.

Site 2 site between the 2 VNET thru VPN gateway.
Also you have to make the machines in Fail over cluster so as they form a cluster.